# How properly execute external script (in simple way)?

Tags: shell, groovy

I have to use groovy for simple parsing output and then I need execute external script. No problem with parsing, but executing in groovy (and art. regards that issue) proved to be a bit confusing. Whole investigation came my up to simple question; why this one:

```
def p1 = "ls -la".execute()
```

works good, when below one will not even start? :

```
def p2 = "~/run_perl_test.pl".execute()
```

(No problem with Perl here - executing script in same manner from shell works fine.)
Of course printing *p1.text* gave proper *ls -la* output and *p2.text* return only empty string.

What am I doing wrong here? Could I debug it more somehow (beyond the prints)? (now I just running it from Jenkins, only there I've got interpreter. No IDE and stuff)

Comment: Does groovy recognize `~/` as a shortcut to your home dir?

Comment: Does: `def p2 = [ 'perl', '-w', '/full/path/to/run_perl_test.pl' ].execute().text` work?

Comment: @TLP, it's not an issue here. Path is an example, I pass full correct path here.

Comment: @tim_yates I've tried to pass full command as a list of strings, but unfortunately same results :(

Comment: @oundru87 It is a very bad idea to post code you are not actually using. About 6/10 on the poor question scale. Imagine you were working in a busy TV repair shop, someone calls up and gives information on their problem, and you spend 10 minutes looking up that information, you call them back and they say "Oh, that was just an example. Here's the real info:" That would be annoying, wouldn't you say?

Comment: OK, mea culpa. Didn't realize that simplification of paths could be misleading. I've only tried to make my question shorter and more readable..

Comment: @oundru87 Its ok, its not like you're the only one. I'm just saying, don't do it. Have you tried using the Perl executable to run the file? `"perl ~/run_perl.pl"`

Answer (score 0):

If the script starts with `#!/usr/bin/perl` or similar, you should just need to do:

```
[ 'sh', '-c', '~/run_perl_test.pl' ].execute().text
```

So that the `~` gets expanded.  Or you could expand it yourself by:

```
"${System.properties.'user.home'}/run_perl_test.pl".execute().text
```

If it's just a perl script, then I believe you would need

```
[ 'sh', '-c', 'perl -w ~/run_perl_test.pl' ].execute().text
```

Or again, expand the `~` yourself in code:

```
"perl -w ${System.properties.'user.home'}/run_perl_test.pl".execute().text
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried few combinations, but still nothing (I know, it should work!). In case when I added path to shell/path to perl version, still nothing happened. When I've added both 'sh -c perl -w ...' Jenkins completely went crazy and job just hang. What I should try now?